# remove parent folders in dataset

Tags: python, directory, path, subdirectory

I want to remove parent folders in this dataset.

[image]

for example I want to change the directory from "images256/w/waiting_room/*" to "images256/wating_room/*" for all of parent's folders what you see I've deleted "w" parent folder from directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you flagged this question with python, I assume you want to use python for this. You can use the `shutil` package for this

```
import os
import shutil

base_folder = "images256"
inter_folder = "w"
child_folder = "waiting_room"

source_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, inter_folder, child_folder)
destination_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, child_folder)


for file_name in os.listdir(source_folder):

    source = os.path.join(source_folder, file_name)
    destination = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)


    shutil.move(source, destination)
    print('Moved:', file_name)
shutil.rmtree(source_folder)
```

You can also use shutil.copytree(src,dest) but since we are talking about datasets, that may be large, moving the files will be faster and you won't run out of space. Be sure to only have files inside your source folder, otherwise maybe rewrite it to a recursive function to move all contents in deeper nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to test this code tomorrow morning :))

Comment: Don't sweat it. :) Be sure that you use your full paths or be careful of your relative paths. If it works, I'd appreciate it if you accept the answer.